# Замена ссылок

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Сделал замену ссылок типа site.ru/id1, но не могу разобраться как сделать замену ссылки типа site.ru/name? обе ссылки ведут на профиль пользователя. в начале должна быть проверка есть ли такой файл. Ещё в настройках прописано дописывание к ссылкам .php типа site.ru/index

Пробовал с помощью регулярки но так и не смог сделать "выбрать всё с конца строки кроме «id»" из этой регулярки `id([0-9a-zA-Z.-_]+)$`

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule id([0-9]+)$ test.php [NC]
RewriteRule id([0-9a-zA-Z.-_]+)$ test.php [NC]
```

И что значат буквы в конце в [квадратных скобках] ?

Comment: [NC] - это флаг mod_rewrite. В данном случае NC - нечувствительность к регистру символов

Comment: Посмотрите здесь, может поможет разобраться: [Шпаргалка по mod_rewrite](http://www.exlab.net/tools/sheets/mod_rewrite.html) Также полезная статья на хабре [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/) Ну и [сайтик по .htaccess](http://www.htaccess.net.ru/)